# How to check the existing MySQL server if Strong Password Encryption is enabled?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Around half a year ago I have installed the latest MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/${MYSQL_8_file}
dpkg -i ${MYSQL_8_file}
apt update
apt install -y mysql-server
```

I tried to upgrade the apt

```
apt full-upgrade -y
```

And now I got a MySQL splash screen that seems to be taking me through the installation of MySQL. I didn't quite expect to see that.

[image]

Now it comes to the question of enabling `use Strong Password Encryption`.

I can't see anything in my previous bash installation script, that has enabled or disabled this deliberately. How can I check if this is currently enabled or not so that I don't break the database?

Comment: Normally you either do a manual installation (your `wget` and `dpkg -i package-file` commands) **or** install the Ubuntu supplied version of mysql-server (`apt-get` simply downloads and installs from the Ubuntu software repositories) and **not both**.  It is hard to tell which MySQL you have actually been using... But `apt`  is typically used to manage the Ubuntu supplied packages.

Comment: When I do `which mysqld`, it shows me only one installation `/usr/sbin/mysqld`. Therefore I don't have multiple installations. Very strange

Answer (score 0):

Starting from MySQL 8 (which you have installed initially) strong password encryption is a default setting. Since it was installed (somehow) in non-interactive mode then my guess is that you are already have it enabled.

So - if you confirm and select it while upgrading it shouldn't break anything.

Every database user has verification type set individually so theoretically even changing default verification type will just tell mysqld to set legacy type auth for new users.

Just to be sure - make a backup of all DB's you have on this machine and upgrade mysql-server to the latest version.